# Android BroadcastReceiver onReceive() not triggered

Tags: android, intentfilter, android-pendingintent

A simple implementation of AlarmManager and BroadcastReceiver, I just can't get it to run. Since a lot of the code cannot be checked with Logs (this is what I usually do) I thought I'll ask you guys. The onCreate() method in my main activity calls:

```
    private void setupBackupService() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, BackupReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
    alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() +
            10 * 1000, 100, pIntent);

    Log.i("main","hello");

}
```

BacupReceiver looks like:

```
    public class BackupReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Log.i("BroadcastReceiver","hello");
}

}
```

and a piece of the manifest file:

```
   <receiver android:name="BackupReceiver" >          
   </receiver>
```

Comment: try changing to like this <receiver
            android:name="com.example.android.blah.BackupReceiver"
            android:exported="false" ></receiver>

Answer (score 3):

Try to modify your manifest :

```
 <receiver android:name=".BackupReceiver"/>
```

or use `android:name="your.app.package.BackupReceiver"` 
hope that helps

Comment: You don't need `android:enabled="true"`, that is the default setting. The real problem here is that the `android:name` attribute didn't contain the preceding "." character so that Android couldn't find the component when the alarm went off.

Comment: @David Yes, you are right. I just copy-pasted from somewhere of my code, i will update the answer, thanx

Answer (score 1):

If your plan is to start a service with the `AlarmManager`, you can skip the broadcast receiver completely and just use `pIntent.getService`.

A tutorial about it:
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html#scheduleservice_scheduling

Comment: Will this service then be able to complete a particular task every 5 minutes? Undisturbed?

Comment: You need to use Android's `WakeLock`s (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html) to make sure that the service keeps on running on the background. Otherwise the phone might go to sleep right after `onStartCommand` returns. Keep in mind though that running something that keeps the phone awake every 5 minutes can be very bad for the battery life.

Comment: And to add to the previous, a broadcast receiver is not meant for any actual processing, it's supposed to be a very short and simple piece of code. Any longer operations should be done in a service anyway. Also keep in mind that just having a service doesn't mean that the code is run in a separate thread on the background. The service code such as `onStartCommand` is run in the GUI thread and you have to set up threads (e.g. `AsyncTask`s) yourself to do actual background processing.

Comment: And what about increasing the pause from 5 minutes to one hour? using alarmmanager is the best way to go right?

Comment: Yep, AlarmManager is good for all periodic activities that you want to run even when the app is not active. Just remember that alarms are cleared when the phone is rebooted, so you might need to reset your alarm using a boot broadcast receiver (ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETE) or when your app is started the first time after boot.